# Error when listing all routes in Laravel, ReflectionException Class "Postcontroller" does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

A basic laravel app with Postcontroller is been created using

```
php artisan make:controller Postcontroller --resource
```

however when listing the routes (`php artisan route:list`)

it shows error that   *Class "Postcontroller" does not exist* eve though it exists.

[image]

Comment: the fact that it thinks you are referring to `Postcontroller` and not `App\Http\Controllers\Postcontroller` is interesting ... is there another place where that controller is referenced besides what is shown?

Comment: Start over, and use the command `php artisan make:model Post -mcr`

Comment: did you run **php artisan route:clear**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please double-check that inside the Postcontroller.php the class name is proper.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class Postcontroller extends Controller{

}
```

Then, clear the cache:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

Comment: Thanks Nasreen, what does namespace do ?

Comment: @AnoopKGeorge you can check in the laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers